# Get node_modules directory

Tags: node.js, npm

We have an internal npm package lets call it A. I have a script in there which references some files in it's node_modules directory as such

```
var path = require('path');
/**
 * Contains tasks for webdriver
 */
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    var test_protractor_bin = path.resolve(__dirname + '/../node_modules/protractor/bin');
    grunt.config.merge({

        exec: {
            webdriverUpdate: {
                command: test_protractor_bin + '/webdriver-manager update'
            },
            // test runs that crash can leave zombie chromedriver processes. call this to kill them.

        }
    });
};
```

I have another package B which lists package A in its package.json. Currently we have few folks who use npm 2 and we are having few folks who want to use npm 3. It looks like the modules are installed no longer nested in npm 3 so using relative paths doesn't work for me. I know in the require statement we can give the package name in the path and npm will resolve it for it me. Is there a way to do the same thing in the script it self so that I don't have to worry about how npm install's the  node modules?

Comment: **See [How to find the `package.json` file from within an `npm` script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41273499/find-the-package-json-file-from-within-an-npm-script-that-runs-on-preinstall)**

Answer (score 2):

'[get-installed-path](https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-installed-path)' allows you to find the installed path of a package.