# Find the package.json file from within an npm script that runs on preinstall

Tags: node.js, npm

So I need to read the `package.json` before installing a new package via npm.

## Why reading package.json in the first place?

I am using npm for CSS components that are individually versioned and can have inter dependencies. *(No javascript is delivered)*

Looking for version conflicts for a bunch of dependencies I need to detect when `package A` requires `package C@1.0.0` and `package B` requires `package C@2.0.0` and deal with it.

Npm (as of version 3) deals with these issues by nesting a conflicting module deeper inside the tree. You now end up with both versions of the same module. CSS has a global namespace and a mixin (in Sasss case) would then overwrite each other and break your CSS.

This flat dependency issue is perfectly outlined in the npm blog: http://blog.npmjs.org/post/101775448305/npm-and-front-end-packaging

Even not considering our specific use case it strikes me as odd that you don't have access to the `package.json` in `preinstall` and `postinstall` scripts. They seem to be just for that use case.

## What I tried

My `package.json` of the package I'm installing looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "testmodule",
    "version": "0.3.6",
    "description": "TODO",
    "scripts": {
        "preinstall": "npm i some-script && some-script",
    },
    "author": "TODO",
    "license": "MIT"
}
```

Inside that `some-script` package I run:

```
console.log( process.cwd() );
console.log( __dirname );
```

I then run:

```
~/path/to/folder $ npm i testmodule
```

This will result in:

```
$ npm i testmodule

> testmodule@0.3.6 preinstall /path/to/folder/node_modules/.staging/testmodule-5cc9d333
> some-script

/path/to/folder/node_modules/.staging/test-module-5cc9d333
/path/to/folder/node_modules/.staging/test-module-5cc9d333/node_modules/some-script
```

**Now I totally get that I can't really access the root of where `npm i` was ran because my script was run by a subprocess of npm and has an entirely different root.**

I then thought `npm root` should keep track where the actual root was for me and passed that as a parameter to my script from inside the testmodule package.json:

```
{
        "name": "testmodule",
        "version": "0.3.6",
        "description": "TODO",
        "scripts": {
                "preinstall": "npm i some-script && some-script \"$(npm root)\"",
        },
        "author": "TODO",
        "license": "MIT"
}
```

Unfortunately that also defaults back to a staging path:

```
/path/to/folder/node_modules/.staging/testmodule-5cc9d333/node_modules
```

I filed [an issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/15277) with the registry but not holding my hopes up for them to get to that in time. Also my script needs to work on older npm installations.

In the meantime I came up with something like that inside my `some-script`:

```
let pgkPath = process.cwd().split('/node_modules/')[0];
```

That will return `/path/to/folder/` which is correct but it makes the assumption no-one runs an `npm i` inside a folder incidentally named `node_modules`... Seems hacky.

## Question

How can I access the path to the package.json from inside an npm script that is run via preinstall? To me that seems like something not too outrageous to ask for?

Comment: This sounds very much like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) - what are you trying to do that requires you to read that `package.json` to being with? And not "I'm trying to get value `...` out ", *why* are you doing that? Because there's a good bet there's a better way to do what you need that you simply didn't know about.

Comment: Good point. I'll added that to the question. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Dude, what? This is literally what NPM already does for you, it's one of most important things it does, in fact, because if you had to do that by hand it'd be an intractable problem. What arcane real world example have you run into where NPM is not managing concurrent versioning correctly in the dependency tree? In the example you give, NPM would *not* overwrite one version with another, it will see the versioning conflict and have both versions reside deeper in the tree.

Comment: Front end use case. Read: http://blog.npmjs.org/post/101775448305/npm-and-front-end-packaging

Comment: I've read that post a few times in the past, what *real world* example do you have? Now is the time to come up with a [mcve] and put that in your post because even these days we do front end bundling with things like browserify or webpack or rollup, and we can tell those exactly what they need to use, as well as npm scripts for running "shx mkdirp assets && cp node_modules/jquery/..../moo/thing.js assets" as a bootstrapping command that doesn't require guess work. It's your codebase, you peg versions and then always know what's in it.

Comment: Think Sass only :)

Comment: I use sass in my day job as part of npm managed projects, so... what should I be thinking? you compile sass to CSS server side, and the client only loads of .css files. What are the versioning issues around that that you're running into? =)

Comment: Each module is individually versioned and has dependencies. Have a look at: https://github.com/dominikwilkowski/sass-versioning

Comment: right, but if you peg the versions (so not `^a.b.c` but literally `a.b.c`) your dependencies are fixed. Also note that npm scripts get their run environment ammended with all locally installed modules, so instead of calling `./node_modules/.bin/sassdoc` you can just call `sassdoc` directly (*only* in the npm script call of course, but that's typically the only thing you need when you have a package.json). I honestly don't see anything obvious here that's version-conflicty-weird.

Comment: @Dominik take a look at this
https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc/blob/master/lib/config-util.js#L14

Note how they use the https://www.npmjs.com/package/find-up package to solve that issue.
Does that works for you?

Comment: @nico yeah that's how I'm doing it now. I was hoping for a better interface from npm. Any API really :) Thanks though

Comment: You asked how to do something that you come out with it after think how could you solve a problem that you are facing now, could you tell us the problem? I'm really curious to know what's the problem

Comment: The use case is using npm for Sass modules that are individually versioned. You need a flat directory structure and if each module is dependent on another versions then you can run into conflicts which are solved by nesting the conflicting module deeper in the tree by npm. That would break Sass. I am building a script that checks for conflicts and errors out on install when that occurs. No js. Cleared with npm directly as a use case. The problem is always around flat dependency structures and perfectly described in: http://blog.npmjs.org/post/101775448305/npm-and-front-end-packaging

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand your use-case entirely, but to answer your specific question of finding a parent `package.json` from a preinstall script:

Pass `$(cd .. && npm prefix)` as an argument to your script, then load `./package.json`.

[`npm prefix`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/prefix) will return the closest parent directory to contain a `package.json` file, which when invoked from the `..` directory, should return the parent npm package's path.

```
{
        "name": "testmodule",
        "version": "0.3.6",
        "description": "TODO",
        "scripts": {
            "preinstall": "npm i some-script && some-script \"$(cd .. && npm prefix)\"",
        },
        "author": "TODO",
        "license": "MIT"
}
```